# Can PHP create an MS Access database from scratch?

Tags: php, pdo, ms-access-2013

This is a pretty straightforward question:  is there any way of creating an MS Access database file from scratch using PHP?  I strongly suspect the answer is no out of the box (using PDO with the ODBC driver pretty clearly demands an existing file for the connection string), but perhaps there’s a library I haven’t found.  Currently I’m using an empty .accdb file as a template and making a copy before CREATE-ing tables in it, but I’d like to skip that step for security reasons if nothing else.

Comment: why would you even consider doing this?

Comment: *Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.* I am sure there is *a* way cause at the end of the day it's all bits and bytes, but why not use an existing DB technology like MySql. If you're looking to create a file that you can share, there's MySQLite.

Comment: @Joshua access not MySQL

Comment: "but why not use an existing DB technology like MySql." Will edit to make that statement more clear though.

Comment: Having done a little work with Access via PDO ODBC on Linux, I'd say you probably can't do it, and even if you could, you'd have more fun gouging your eyeballs out. Sure, you can do queries and such, but you don't have good error reporting like what you get with MySQL or SQLite3. App portability would suffer, because Access specific ODBC drivers are different between operating systems. You would hate yourself and development would be tedious, confusing, and miserable. PHP has great support for other databases, and you should for sure work with one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the ODBC driver needs a database(!) to connect to.

Your current approach, copying a template file, is clean and simple and, except if the file can be replaced, also safe.